# API for uploading an APNs Authentication Key to firebase

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications

I would like automate setting the APNs Authentication Key for push notifications, as well as the Team ID for an iOS App in firebase.

Therefore I would need to do this using an API (Rest, Go, Node.js, ...) Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to firebase support this is currently not possible. (Answer from May 2021)